# Scope of iteratee too wide

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t a duplicate variable name be declared in a nested local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156449/why-cant-a-duplicate-variable-name-be-declared-in-a-nested-local-scope)

I noticed that the following code didn't compile. Quick fix was to recall the outer variable `thing` to something else but then I started to think and realized that the internal scope should end **within** the `foreach` loop. I sure can't use the internal variable outside it.

Shouldn't I be able to reuse the name `thing` outside the loop? Why?

```
String aggregate = String.Empty;
foreach (Thing thing in things)
  aggregate += thing.Value;

Thing thing = new Thing();
```

Comment: Consider using LINQ Aggregate for this particular construct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, as surprising it might feel, the variable's scope is wider than what you'd expect. Give this code a try.

```
String aggregate = String.Empty;
foreach (Thing thing in things)
  aggregate += thing.Value;
foreach (Thing thing in things)
  aggregate += thing.Value;
```

It'll compile just fine. However, if you declare the `thing` outside as you did, the declaration span is **outwards**. It gets me too, sometime. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't I be able to reuse the name thing outside the loop? Why?

The problem is that the *scope* of the variable in the last line extends *up*... it covers the whole block. So the problem is actually that you can't declare the `thing` variable *for the loop* as that clashes with another variable which is already in scope.

From section 8.5.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> The scope of a local variable declared in a *local-variable-declaration* is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the *local-variable-declaration* of the local variable. Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name.

That last sentence is the one your code is violating.

Just use different names.

Comment: Wow, I learned something there. Thanks Jon! On that note, are you implying that even if a variable is **coded** on the tenth line of the scope, in the IL it's **declared** at the top?

Comment: +1... Do you count how many times you answered this one already :)

Comment: @BigM Kinda, sorta. I may be wrong but: the generated IL will have different values for say its `stdloc.#` instructions but otherwise it's identical. `object B; object A = new object(); B = new Object()` results in IL `newobj; stloc.1; newobj; stloc.0` whereas `object A = new object(); object B = new object()` results in IL `newobj; stloc.0; newobj; stloc.1;` There is no explicit "declaration at the top" in IL (AFAIK), it just directly references the location numbers in-line. I guess you could look at that hard-coding of location numbers as equivalent to being declared "at the top" sort of.

Comment: @BigM: No, it's definitely declared on the tenth line - but its scope extends to the start of the block.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks, I apprecaite it!