# Name a parameter inside an anonymous method

Tags: c#

I'm creating an anonymous method to generate a radom string.

Before declaring the method, I didn't declare any parameter with the name `id`.
But I couldn't still define `string id = string.Empty;` inside the method.

```
// No parameter within name `id` here...

Func<Task<string>> getIdAsync = null;
getIdAsync = async () =>
{
   // string id = string.Empty; // error here. try to use `_id` instead of `id`
   string _id = string.Empty;

   // logic...

   return _id;
};

// _id = ""; // we cann't re-use `_id` here, but `_id` can use `id` below

// `id` is declared after the method
string id = await getIdAsync();
```

Maybe I misunderstood but I think it should throw me the error when (only in this case):

```
// declare `id` before
string id = string.Empty;

Func<Task<string>> getIdAsync = null;
getIdAsync = async () =>
{
   /*
    * A local or parameter named 'id' cannot be declared in this scope 
    * because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
    */
   string id = string.Empty;

   // logic...       
};

id = await getIdAsync();
```

Can anyone correct me?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @roryap I've written the error message inside the second: `A local or parameter name 'id' cannot be declared.....`

Comment: You can't do it in both cases for the same reason, whats not clear? You can however use the same `id` variable (not saying that it is good practice)

Comment: @SimpleVar I think the first case should be valid because I've declare `id` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.

You are trying to redeclare the variable `id`.

The solution will depend on what you are trying to do. If you want to set `id` then simply remove the type definition;

```
getIdAsync = async () =>
{
   id = string.Empty;

   // logic...       
};
```

However, this isn't good practice as `id` could get overwitten by code outside your async method - unless you actually want this. If this is just a variable local to the scope of the anonymous method then rename it:

```
getIdAsync = async () =>
{
   string localId = string.Empty;

   // logic...       
};
```

It's the same as if you were declaring an object of the same name inside an `if` statement or loop.

Comment: @SimpleVar's comment said: using `id = string.Empty;` (in your first case) is not a good practice

Comment: @HappyCoding It isn't - if you can update the variable elsewhere then it could get overwitten.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't care what order you declare your local variables with respect to your delegate method because it doesn't know when you're going to use your delegate.  So regardless of whether or not you have this statement before or after your delegate declaration, you'll still have a conflict:

```
string id = await getIdAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156449), although that question is dealing with a nested scope rather than an anonymous function, but the reasoning is the same.

The scope of `id` is the *entire function*, not just the code *after* declaration.  Since there's no way do disambiguate between the "outer" `id` variable and the `id` variable local to the anonymous function, the compiler throws an error to make you specify *which* variable you are referring to.