# local scope contradiction in loops

Tags: c#, loops, compiler-errors

I'm confused why is there compiler error **CS0136 "A local or parameter named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"** in loops of that kind?
Isn't first *a* enclosed inside the loop?

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int a = 0;
        }

        int a = 1;
    }
```

If not, why is there compiler **Error CS0841   Cannot use local variable 'b' before it is declared** in this variant

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int a = b;
        }

        int b = 1;
    }
```

Is there any contradiction here and why is this restriction made for?

Comment: You can for sure use `a` inside another scoped block (enclose it inside `{ }`). I am sometimes doing this to avoid naming differently things like `item`.

Comment: @Sinatr I found it too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your first function, the function itself is a variable scope. As Sinatr mentioned, you can declare an enclosing scope, but this scope cannot contradict the general function's scope. As mentioned by John Skeet ([Why can't a duplicate variable name be declared in a nested local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156449/why-cant-a-duplicate-variable-name-be-declared-in-a-nested-local-scope)), your problem is that the compiler thinks that your attempt to declare a new `a` in a child scope is actually an illegal attempt to reference your parent `a`, which has not yet been declared.

In your second function, the difference is that you are attempting to address the variable `b` before it is declared. You are calling

```
int a = b;
```

within a loop, and then only after the loop is ended do you call

```
int b = 1;
```