# Discord.Net 1.0 How to use ModifyAsync/How to modify contents of a message

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to edit a message that my bot sent, but I can't seem to find any answers by myself. For context, the old message is a "waiting" message until the API I'm using retrieves the data I want. The new message is what the data that was received.

This is my current solution:

```
var msg = await ReplyAsync("old message");

//... unrelated code ...    

await msg.DeleteAsync();
await ReplyAsync("new message");
```

The arguments for `ModifyAsync();` are `Action<MessageProperties> funct, [RequestOptions options]`.

I've attempted to use `ModifyAsync();` myself, to no avail.

All I want to do is modify the content of the message, and all of the research I've done leads to earlier versions of the Discord.Net library.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and found this : https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/474

I know it isn't modifying a message but it works the same way, you pass it a lambda expression:

```
var Message = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("test message");

await Message.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = "test [edited]");
```

Comment: This method doesn't actually work. This is the error message returned: `A local or parameter named 'msg' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`

Comment: This solution does work, the error is caused by something on your end. You probably have a variable name that is the same as another.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156449/why-cant-a-duplicate-variable-name-be-declared-in-a-nested-local-scope Take a look at this link, it should be of use. @xubiod

Answer (score 0):

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test.");
await Context.Message.ModifyAsync(m => { m.Content = "Test [Edited]."; });
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Can you do this with a message which is nothing but an uploaded file?