# Modifying WebHook Message With Discord.Net c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webhooks, discord.net

```
 using (DiscordWebhookClient client = new DiscordWebhookClient(WEBHOOK_URL))
{
   ulong z = 42342340290226;

   client.ModifyMessageAsync(z);//Not sure how I would edit this message. The documentation is confusing.
}
```

Im not sure how to use this ModifyMessage function. Also, do I need to use a Async Function? I am just calling it without using any ASYNC. Im not sure if that is ok. The send message works, but second function im not sure how to work it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.Net 1.0 How to use ModifyAsync/How to modify contents of a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095112/discord-net-1-0-how-to-use-modifyasync-how-to-modify-contents-of-a-message)

Comment: You need to await the Async calls if you need them to run in sequence

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I am not sure what you mean by this. I just want them to run one at a time. So my current method is correct, right?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Also, I just need to edit the message using the ID. The first line that sends the message was just a one time thing. Now I will just edit that message.

Comment: Action<MessageProperties> funct @ChrisSchaller what is that used for? How do I use this to modify my message. This parameter is giving me trouble.

Comment: No, it's not correct. It's highly likely that this is going to dispose the client while the request is in flight. If a method returns a task, you need to do something with it (ideally await it).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Can I please have some guidance on how to do this and how to send the request to modify the message? I have had no help.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you should await the async call. This ensures that the action is executed in a predictable fashion. The intend is to execute it right now and to wait for the result of the action.

That being said, the discord documentation describes this method as follows:

```
public Task ModifyMessageAsync(ulong messageId, Action<WebhookMessageProperties> func, RequestOptions options = null)
```

The second parameter describes a delegate based on WebhookMessageProperties. It can easily be defined by a lambda, like such:

```
x => { }
```

Now bear in mind the x is arbitrary, you can chose whatever designation you like, even whole words, I just kept it short for the example.

Between the bracelets, you can use access any properties that are in the WebhookMessageProperties class, by using x.SomeProperty. Where SomeProperty has to be a known property of that class if that makes sense.

One of the known properties is for example:

```
string Content { get; set; }
```

So here is how you can use a lambda to change the Content property:

```
using (DiscordWebhookClient client = new DiscordWebhookClient(WEBHOOK_URL))
{
    ulong z = 42342340290226;

    await client.ModifyMessageAsync(z, x => 
    {
        x.Content = "This is the updated message content";
    });
```

}

If you want to update multiple properties at the same time, you can just add another line inside the lambda.